# Hollywood.....?

Tags: single-word-requests

The bad movies.  The rice-cake caloric value ones that go *bang* too loud and too often.  These have a deserved bad reputation, and in turn have given “Hollywood” a bad reputation.

(Setting aside for a moment the fact many such movies are no longer made in Hollywood, or perhaps created and headed by non natives.  Nor would any respectable top 100 list of movies not be well represented, if not utterly dominated, by Hollywood productions – but anyway...)

I'm going for the pop empty-headed understanding of “Hollywood”.

The word I'm looking for begins with a ”C” - I think.  It means a bunch of useless things.  Worthless twigs.  Ignoble and unimportant.  Dime a dozen.

- Hollywood *chattel* [no]
- Hollywood *chortal* [no]
- Hollywood *chuffle* [no]

…?

Comment: _Hollywood cartel_? That's a phrase at least, though I'm not quite sure what exactly it is your question is…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Chaff,*** perhaps? That could actually be worthless twigs, or stalks, and is certainly used figuratively:

> The husks of corn or other seed separated by winnowing or threshing.
>   Chopped hay and straw used as fodder.
>
> Worthless things; rubbish:
>   *he hopes to separate scientifically supported claims from pseudoscientific chaff*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chaff)